# Is there a way to force a NIC’s link state “UP” when disconnected in Esxi?

Tags: esxi, nic

I was setting SR-IOV in Esxi using a Mellanox Connectx-4 Lx card and encountered a problem:
The only port of the card back-to-back connects to a PC, not a switch, so the link state of the card sometimes is “down” when the PC powered off.
When the card is not “up”, its SR-IOV VF in VM shows “down” either. Thus, VMs cannot talk to each other unless that PC power on.
Is there any way to resolve this in Esxi, like something what ip command in linux do, force nic link state or enable VF individually even when the card is disconnected?

I tried esxcli network nic up command but didn’t work.